# htaccess rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this rule where I want the page to just render my static content.

```
RewriteRule ^videos\/coverage\/view\/236159\-([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) http: //website.com/static/236159.html [NC]
```

However, this doesn't work. It works with a L tag but then the URL is different:

```
RewriteRule ^videos\/coverage\/view\/236159\-([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) http: //website.com/static/236159.html [L, NC]
```

My goal is to keep the URL the same but the content different. Can anyone point out to what flags are needed in order to get this working properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you stay on the same machine, use relative URIs:

```
RewriteRule ^videos/coverage/view/236159-([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ static/236159.html [NC]
```